# codeigniter send variable for views

Tags: codeigniter, variables, object

My controller page is:

```
class Anasayfa extends CI_Controller {

public $viewData;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->viewData = new stdClass();
    $this->viewData->sayfa = 'main';
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('common/template', $this->viewData);
}
```

My view page is:

```
$this->load->view('common/header'); $this->load->view('common/navbar'); $this->load->view('common/solmenu'); $this->load->view('common/slider'); $this->load->view($sayfa); $this->load->view('common/footer');
```

But in browser:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: sayfa
>
> Filename: common/template.php
>
> Line Number: 6

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->viewData = array();
    $this->viewData['sayfa'] = 'main';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an array instead of object:

```
$this->viewData['sayfa'] = 'main';
```

[Adding Dynamic Data to the View](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view).

Comment: it's possible but i want to this $this->viewData->sayfa = 'main';

Comment: Not in CodeIgniter until you change core class(es) in system directory which is never good solution (updating framework, compatibility with other CI packages, etc).